# When is $C$ a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory

For some $x\in G$, define $C:=\{g^{-1}xg\mid g \in G\}$. When is $C$ a subgroup of $G$?

Certainly if every element of $G$ commutes with $x$ (if $x$ is in the center), then $C \leq G$. Are there any other cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x$ is in the center then $g^{-1}xg = xg^{-1}g = x$; hence $C = \{x\}$. This cannot be a subgroup unless $x$ is the identity.

More generally, for $C$ to be a subgroup, it must contain the identity. This means that $g^{-1}xg = 1$ for some $g$. This gives $x = 1$ again.

Comment: Note that the smallest subgroup containing $C$ is $\langle C \rangle$, and this is in fact a *normal* subgroup of $G$.